# Xamarin.Forms TabbedPage event when current tab is tapped to refresh the page

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms to build an iOS/Android app, and have a TabbedPage.

If a user is already on Tab 2, and Tab2 is clicked, and I want either the tab2 to refresh, or for a function of my own to run so I can refresh it myself.

Is there a way to do this within Xamarin.Forms or a way to do it with custom renderers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how I ended up solving the issue. My TabbedPage consisted of a NavigationPage for each tab, so if you are not using navigation pages your code will have to change a little bit but only slightly. You can put your "refresh" logic inside of `OnTabbarControllerItemSelected` for iOS and `OnTabbarControllerItemSelected` for Android. Check out the code below.

Android Renderer (courtesy of Mike Ma)

```
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainTabbedPage), typeof(MainPageRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class MainPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer, TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener
    {
        private MainTabbedPage _page;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                _page = (MainTabbedPage)e.NewElement;
            }
            else
            {
                _page = (MainTabbedPage)e.OldElement;
            }

        }
        async void TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            await _page.CurrentPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

iOs Renderer:

```
using UIKit;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainTabbedPage), typeof(MainPageRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class MainPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        private MainTabbedPage _page;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                _page = (MainTabbedPage)e.NewElement;
            }
            else
            {
                _page = (MainTabbedPage)e.OldElement;
            }

            try
            {
                var tabbarController = (UITabBarController)this.ViewController;
                if (null != tabbarController)
                {
                    tabbarController.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }

        private async void OnTabbarControllerItemSelected(object sender, UITabBarSelectionEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (_page?.CurrentPage?.Navigation != null && _page.CurrentPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 0)
            {
                await _page.CurrentPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When using `ToolbarPlacement.Bottom`, you need another listener: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/133429/how-do-i-get-the-tabreselect-event-with-tabbar-at-the-bottom-on-android

Answer (score 4):

Do some research of Android Native `TabLayout` the click event call back function is `OnTabReselected`

And according to the [TabbedPageRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/TabbedPageRenderer.cs) source code. You can find `OnTabReselected` is not be implemented.

So I created a customer render for `TabbedPage` as following code and implement the `OnTabReselected` function to change the current page background :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Page1), typeof(MyTabPageRender))]
namespace XamarinTabbedPage_Demo.Droid
{
    public class MyTabPageRender : TabbedPageRenderer, TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
        void TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            int selectedIndex = tab.Position;
            if (Element.Children.Count > selectedIndex && selectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                Element.CurrentPage = Element.Children[selectedIndex];

                if (selectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    Element.CurrentPage.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mike! This was a huge help to me. I was able to figure out the iOS one later on and will post that here as well this weekend.

Comment: I know this is a really old post but ran across it now. I have tried this approach and it no longer works as the library in question `TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener` is now obsolete. Also the event is never called on the TabbedPage I am using, however I am using Reactive UI and a `ReactiveTabbedPage` so it is possible the event is not fired by it.