# How can I detect the clicking of a tab button in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the code that I have.  I would like to know how I can detect when a user clicks a tab that is already selected as I want to toggle the icon for the aPage between play.png and pause.png plus I also want to call a method on APage.

```cs
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var aPage = new NavigationPage(new APage())
        {
            Title = "Play",
            Icon = "play.png"
        };
        var bPage = new NavigationPage(new BPage())
        { 
            Title = "Settings",
            Icon = "b.png"
        };

        Children.Add(aPage);
        Children.Add(bPage);
    }
}
```

Note that if possible I would like to find a solution that does not involve custom renderers for both iOS and Android.  I'm wondering can I redefine the TabbedPage and put the logic in that class?

Comment: will that help? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90796/tabbedpage-event-on-tab-click-or-refresh-tab-when-same-tab-is-clicked or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801222/xamarin-forms-tabbedpage-event-when-current-tab-is-tapped-to-refresh-the-page

Comment: This is TabbedPage default behavior. If you want to change you need to create custom renders for both iOS and Android.

Comment: @Alan Let me know if I can provide more assistance! When you get a chance, let's mark it as "Answered" to help any devs who may the same question in the future!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know you want to avoid using custom renderers, but this is only possible by using a Custom Renderer.

## Code

#### Xamarin.Android Custom Renderer

```cs
using Android.Content;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(MainPageRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class MainPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer, TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener
    {
        MainPage _page;

        public MainPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
                _page = e.NewElement as MainPage;
            else
                _page = e.OldElement as MainPage;
        }

        void TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Tab Reselected");
            //Handle Tab Reselected
        }
    }
}
```

#### Xamarin.iOS Custom Renderer

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(MainPageRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class MainPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        MainPage _page;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
                _page = e.NewElement as MainPage;
            else
                _page = e.OldElement as MainPage;

            try
            {
                if (ViewController is UITabBarController tabBarController)
                    tabBarController.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }

        void OnTabbarControllerItemSelected(object sender, UITabBarSelectionEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (_page?.CurrentPage?.Navigation != null && _page.CurrentPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Tab Tapped");
                //Handle Tab Tapped
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code credit: [@Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1308743/kyle) https://stackoverflow.com/a/42909203/5953643

Comment: Ha. Two years after I wrote that code, here I am trying to do the same thing again, and I find this answer on a different question, credited to me. I don't even remember writing that answer. Thanks @Brandon!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get selected tab then you need to use **ItemSource** and **SelectedItem** property like ListView.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily in iOS, but in Android you need a custom renderer. Just check this blog 
http://motzcod.es/post/162985782667/dynamically-changing-xamarin-forms-tab-icons-when-select

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `TabbedPage` interited from `MultiPage` that you can check the source from [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/MultiPage.cs). All select, deselect, update, template and logic is implemented here.  You suppose to watch `CurrentPage` property but it has *value check* if already selected, so you cannot use.

Answer (score -2):

```
this.PropertyChanging += async (object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentPage")
            {
                if (this.CurrentPage == null)
                    return;
            }
        };
```